# Android Lock Folder Programatically in SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, file-structure

Is there anyway to make a folder password protected in SD card programmatically so that if i want to access any file in that folder i can access using password otherwise it should not open.

**PS - I am not looking for some encryption alternative.**

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, Android does not offer such a capability.

Comment: Is there any approach you would like to suggest , what if i use Rooted Device ?
Is there anything can be done at File System level ?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: @ʌɐɥqıɐʌ: Sorry, I have not researched those sorts of options.